# Postgres Syntax error at or near "CAST"

Tags: postgresql, casting

According to the docs and this [tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/). I can use;

`CAST ( expression AS type );`

I have a series of values stored as `text` which are monetary values (formatted as 200.00 i want to be `decimal` so I have attempted;

```
SELECT totalvalue 
CAST (table.totalvalue AS decimal(12,2))
FROM table;
```

But this just returns an error on the syntax

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CAST"`

I've tried swapping the type from decimal to  integer but i get the same problem.

Postrgres 9.6.2

Comment: Please show your full query statement. Currently, it looks like your query is only `CAST ...`, which won't work. This should be at least something like `SELECT CAST (table.totalvalue AS decimal(12,2)) FROM table;` as the tutorial you linked does explain.

Comment: Have added full query

Comment: Perhaps you forgot comma after the first column (`totalvalue`). Try:  `SELECT totalvalue,
CAST (table.totalvalue AS decimal(12,2)) FROM table;`

Comment: That worked but when i added this to `UPDATE d_voa_record1
 SET totalvalue =  CAST (totalvalue AS numeric(12,2));` It runs through but doesn't change the records

Comment: Well that statement does not change the _value_ of the column. Why do you expect that to change anything? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: If you want to change column data type, you need to use `ALTER`, see the answer by @michel.milezzi below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're misunderstanding the purpose of `CAST`. Calling `CAST`  will not change the type of your column, but only its value in the moment of `SELECT`. To change its type you must combine `CAST` with an `ALTER COLUMN`:

```
--Changing type of column using cast operator ::
ALTER TABLE d_voa_record1 
    ALTER COLUMN totalvalue TYPE NUMERIC(12,2) USING (totalvalue::NUMERIC(12,2));

--Changing type of column using cast function
ALTER TABLE d_voa_record1 
    ALTER COLUMN totalvalue TYPE NUMERIC(12,2) 
        USING CAST(totalvalue AS NUMERIC(12,2));

--Just changing returned value of column
SELECT CAST(totalvalue AS NUMERIC(12,2)) AS totalvalue_as_numeric,
    totalvalue AS unchanged_totalvalue FROM d_voa_record1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `totalvalue` that you put before `CAST(..)`, and it should work:

```
SELECT 
  CAST (t1.totalvalue AS decimal(12,2))
FROM t1;
```

I also hope that your didn't use `table` as a name for your table, beause it's SQL keyword. If you did, then always double-quote it:

```
SELECT 
  CAST ("table".totalvalue AS decimal(12,2))
FROM "table";
```